# Orchard CMS 1.8.1 - Migrations WithSetting not saving

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have followed all the examples I founded and none works.

My code (in the Migrations.cs)

```
.WithField("PeopleText", f => f
    .OfType("TextField")
    .WithDisplayName("People / Team"))

    //TODO: Not sure why these settings not taking effect!
    .WithSetting("TextFieldSettings.Flavor", "Html") 
    .WithSetting("TextFieldSettings.Required", "true")
```

None of the above 2 settings saved

[image]

I'm not sure it's known bug of version 1.8.1 or I have done something terrible wrong?

Cheers,

Hugh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing your field migration to soon, which causes the `.WithSetting` to chain to the part instead of the field:

```
.WithField("PeopleText", f => f
    .OfType("TextField")
    .WithDisplayName("People / Team")) // <-- here you close your field chain, so everything after this will attach to the part chain
```

If you change it to the following it will work:

```
.WithField("PeopleText", f => f
    .OfType("TextField")
    .WithDisplayName("People / Team")

    .WithSetting("TextFieldSettings.Flavor", "Html") 
    .WithSetting("TextFieldSettings.Required", "true")) // Close field chain here
```

Comment: Nice spotting! I will check this out as soon as I can, thanks